# AddTransient service using info from request

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I've got an app in asp.net core using the built-in DI framework. I'd like to add a per-request (i.e. transient) service to the provider, but I'd like to actually make use of the request in its construction.

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService>(provider => { ... });
```

That's the closest overload I can find, but the `provider` object doesn't have anything about the current request. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do, without upgrading to a more robust DI framework?

Comment: btw. for per request services you use `AddScope` and not `AddTransient`. `AddTransient` will create a new instance for every resolution, i.e. if you inject two services both using the same repository, then both services will get their own instance of the repository, not a shared one for the duration of the request.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you need within the service? The `HttpContext`?  Or something different? `HttpContext` can be injected easily, getting other stuff may be bit harder

Comment: I believe the `HttpContext` should be sufficient, and you're totally right, I meant to use `AddScoped` rather than `AddTransient`. I'm AFK currently, but does `AddScoped` have the overload I'm looking for?

Comment: You can use IHttpContextAccessor to get HttpContext.

Comment: @gzak: No, but I was going to suggest the same as Pawel. Your implementation of `IMyService` could just simply inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in it's constructor. In case you'd needed more than `IHttpContextAccessor`, you'd need to create a factory class and pass the parameter within the controller or the action to the factory method and then create your dependency there with the required request parameters

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` was exactly what I needed, if one of you wants to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it here (not sure who should get the credit for this one though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As posted in the comments, you can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your services and access it, if the `HttpContext` is the only thing you need.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly HttpContext context;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        if(IHttpContextAccessor==null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));

        context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
}
```

However, if you need something that's only available in the controller or outside of `HttpContext`, you can create a factory and pass the parameters to the factory

```
public class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory
{
    // injecting the HttpContext for request wide service resolution
    public MyServiceFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) { ... }
    public IMyService Create(IDependency1 dep1, IDependency2 dep 2, string someRuntimeConfig)
    {
        IServiceProvider provider = this.context.RequestServices;

        var myService = new MyService(provider.GetService<ISomeRepository>(), dep1, dep2, someRuntimeConfig);
        return myService;
    }
}
```

and then inject the `IMyServiceFactory` to your classes where you'd need `IMyService`.